# Can I bring cancer meds to Canada?

Tags: canada, health

I am traveling to Canada for two weeks and need to bring my cancer meds. Plus I take calcium tablets everyday. My injection appointment is during the vacation, but I’m planning to bring 2 with me just in case. I'm also bringing 4 boxes of calcium tablets and my others 2 femara and a few vitamins and medication that I regularly take.

How much can I bring? I have the prescriptions and everything prepared.
I tend to misplace things that's why I am planning to bring too much, will it be an issue?

Comment: Please edit information into your earlier question rather than asking a new question.